# How to use jquery dynamic onchange() to show and hide another form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show and hide select form base from previous form using select too, when I run this code , my browser show an error javascript like

```
A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. 
You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.

Script: http://localhost/project/assets/back/js/jquery.min.js:2
```

What's wrong with my code

```
             <?php foreach ($menu as $key => $value): ?>
                  <li>
                    <?php echo $value->page_title ?> <span class="label-page"><?php echo $value->category ?></span>
                    Set as 
                    <select id="menu_main<?php echo $value->id ?>" onchange="main_menu(<?php echo $value->id ?>)">
                      <option value="0">Main Menu</option>
                      <option value="1">Child 1</option>
                      <option value="2">Child 2</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="child_1<?php echo $value->id ?>" style="display: none">
                      <option>--Select Parent--</option>
                      <optgroup label="Category">
                        <option value="1">Kategori 1</option>
                        <option value="2">Kategori 2</option>
                      </optgroup>
                      <optgroup label="Label">
                        <option value="1">Label 1</option>
                        <option value="2">Label 2</option>
                      </optgroup>
                    </select>
                </li>    
             <?php endforeach ?>
```

Here is my Javascript

```
function main_menu(id){      
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#menu_main"+id).change(function () {
          $(this).find("option:selected").each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr("value") == "1") {
              $("#child_1"+id).show();
            }
          });          
        }).change();
      });
    }
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Why are you adding another `change` handler in the function that's called when the menu is changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're causing infinite recursion. When you change the menu, it calls `main_menu(id)`. This adds another change handler with `$("#menu_main"+id).change(...)` and then calls `.change()` on the same element. This then calls `main_menu(id)` again, which adds another change handler, and calls `.change()`. And so on and so on.

Get rid of the `onchange` in the HTML, and just bind the event handler in the document ready function.

Use DOM navigation functions to get to the child menu after the main menu.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu_main").change(function() {
        if (this.value == "1") {
            $(this).siblings(".child_menu").show();
        }
    }).change();
});
```

Give all the `menu_mainXXX` selects `class="menu_main"`, and the child menus `class="child_menu"` so that the above selector will work.

PHP/HTML:

```
         <?php foreach ($menu as $key => $value): ?>
              <li>
                <?php echo $value->page_title ?> <span class="label-page"><?php echo $value->category ?></span>
                Set as 
                <select class="menu_main" id="menu_main<?php echo $value->id ?>">
                  <option value="0">Main Menu</option>
                  <option value="1">Child 1</option>
                  <option value="2">Child 2</option>
                </select>
                <select class="child_menu" id="child_1<?php echo $value->id ?>" style="display: none">
                  <option>--Select Parent--</option>
                  <optgroup label="Category">
                    <option value="1">Kategori 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Kategori 2</option>
                  </optgroup>
                  <optgroup label="Label">
                    <option value="1">Label 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Label 2</option>
                  </optgroup>
                </select>
            </li>    
         <?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: can you write your code completely? I try it, but still not works

Comment: Using `this.id` was wrong. I've updated the answer to show how to use DOM navigation to find the child menu.